# How do I use divisibleby() in a for loop to display two columns?

Tags: templating, conditional

I try to write a row in which there are two columns:

```html
<div class="row">
   <div class="block_txt"></div>
   <div class="block_txt"></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
   <div class="block_txt"></div>
   <div class="block_txt"></div>
</div>
{# and so on and so on #}
```

Now maybe there is only one `block_txt` div at the end so I try to wrap the row tag in a `devisibleby` conditional to only write the row tag every second time, or at the end.
It looks like this:

```twig
{% for entry in entriesInYear %}
   {% if loop.index is divisibleby(2) or loop.first %}<div class="row">{% endif %}
      <div class="block_txt">This gets repeated n times</div>
   {% if loop.index is divisibleby(2) or loop.last  %}</div>{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

But that doesn't work the way I want. Every third block_txt isn't wrapped in a row. How do I have to math this? Or is there a better way to write the whole piece?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Instead of using the [`divisibleby`-function](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tests/divisibleby.html) you can use the [`batch`-filter](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/batch.html):

```twig
{% for row in entriesInYear|batch(2) %}
<div class="row">
    {% for entry in row %}
        <div class="block_txt"></div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

If you have 3 entries in `entriesInYear` this code would output:

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="block_txt"></div>
   <div class="block_txt"></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
   <div class="block_txt"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is flippin awesome!

Comment: Very neat trick. Worked perfectly!

Answer (score 10):

If you wish to use divisibleby to solve this problem, the key is in how you use the `loop.index` and `loop.index0` variables.

- `loop.index` counts the iterations in your loop starting with the number 1
- `loop.index0` counts the iterations in your loop starting with the number 0

You can test this with an odd number of items using the range function:

```
{# Loop 3 times  #}
{% for i in 1..3 %}

  {# If index0 is divisible by 2, output the starting row #}
  {% if loop.index0 is divisible by(2) %}
    <div class="row">
  {% endif %}

    {# Output the content #}
    <div class="block_txt"></div>

  {# If index is divisible by 2, output the ending row, and
     if it is the last loop, make sure we close the open row regardless #}
  {% if loop.index is divisible by(2) or loop.last %}
    </div>
  {% endif %}﻿

{% endfor %}
```

And will get your desired output and ensure your last row div element gets closed:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="block_txt"></div>
    <div class="block_txt"></div>
</div>
<div class="row">       
    <div class="block_txt"></div>
</div>
```

You can read more on the [Twig loop variable](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/for.html#the-loop-variable) and the [Twig range function](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/functions/range.html) in the Twig docs.

For your use case, you can then just update the range function to use the variable you need to loop through:

```
{% for entry in entriesInYear %}

  {% if loop.index0 is divisible by(2) %}
    <div class="row">
  {% endif %}

    <div class="block_txt"></div>

  {% if loop.index is divisible by(2) or loop.last %}
    </div>
  {% endif %}﻿

{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. I changed to the batch filter, because the code is much smaller. But the learning effect of posts like this is still big :)