# twig for loop put every 2 elements in a new container

Tags: templating, forloop

I have this loop:

```
{% for div in myHandleHere %}

    <div> {{ block.text }} </div>

{% endfor %}
```

That actually outputs something like:

```
<div> one </div>
<div> two </div>
<div> three </div>
<div> ... </div>
```

What I want is, every 2 div, put them in a new container, like:

```
<div class="container">
    <div> one </div>
    <div> two </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div> three </div>
    <div> ... </div>
</div>
```

Please help

Comment: You can find a similar question/answer here:

http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/472/how-do-i-use-divisibleby-in-a-for-loop-to-display-two-columns/499#499

Comment: Also this question which makes use of twigs batch filter which does exactly this http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/6776/643

Comment: I did this the other day - batch will definitely do what you want. http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/batch.html

Answer (score 9):

I usually do this like so:

```
{% for block in blocks %}
  {% if loop.index0 % 2 == 0 %}
    <div>
  {% endif %}
   {# other stuff #}
  {% if loop.index0 % 2 == 1 or loop.last %}
    </div>
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Or, more generally,

```
{% set cols = 2 %}
{% for block in blocks %}
  {% if loop.index0 % cols == 0 %}
    <div>
  {% endif %}
   {# other stuff #}
  {% if (loop.index0 % cols == cols - 1 or loop.last) %}
    </div>
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 5):

I think `batch` that @Alec Ritson mentioned is definitely the way to go.

However, here's another approach for fun.

You can use [`cycle`](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/functions/cycle.html).

```
{{ cycle('<div>', '') }}
  {{ foo }}
{{ cycle('</div>', '') }}
```

But let me repeat: I really think [`batch`](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/batch.html) is the way to go.